# Zipkin With Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin

I am using spring boot and zipkin.

And using spring slueth to generate trace Id.

Is there a way I can generate this trace Id on my own?

Also I want to log only specific requests say with 500 error or response time > threshold, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To log only request with particular error you can add the log in your exception mapper where you are handling those error.

To show the log for error response you can set like below,

```
    @Autowired
    private Tracer tracer;
```

and set

```
    tracer.addTag("error","Your message")
```